# Add indirect branch target reference manually (xref, crossreference) in Cutter (radare2)?

Tags: radare2

How can I create a reference for an indirect branch instruction

```
blx r0
```

so that the call to the address stored in r0 shows up in the graph?

I've tried flagging the target (function), but that does not get picked up automatically.
Do I need to re-start analysis for the function somehow (how?)?

Comment: Can you share the binary and the relevant offset so we can have a better look? :)

Comment: @Megabeets Sorry, I mustn't... and I have put the project on hold for now. But isn't it kind of a general question anyway (telling radare2/Cutter explicitly how to interpret instructions/data)?

Comment: is it on debug mode? otherwise, if you want radar to figure what's the future value of a register it isn't trivial. But I think that some emulation configurations will be helpful. Try enabling "asm.emu" and "emu.str" and see if this data is available in the comments :)

Comment: Other than that, I suggest looking at the "ax" command and it's subcommands. For example "ax [addr] [at]" will define a code xref

Comment: @Megabeets Thank you, if/when I revisit the project, I'll give that a try.